# Spring Boot DTO values are recevied null

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, null

I send this data from Front with headers {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

```
{
    "libelle": "Article AB",
    "dimension": {
        "id": 0,
        "code": "BIJOUTERIE",
        "label": "Bijouterie"
    },
    "categorie": {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "FEMMES",
        "label": "Femmes"
    },
    "famille": {
        "id": 0,
        "code": "BELDI",
        "label": "Beldi"
    },
    "type": {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "MDEMA",
        "label": "Mdema"
    },
    "picture": "text",
    "description": null,
    "prixVente": 5000,
    "poids": null,
    "status": null,
    "enabled": true,
    "barcode": "4351951317874",
    "annee": null,
    "boitier": null,
    "mouvement": null,
    "taille": null,
    "diametre": null
}
```

I receive it like this, only one value and others are null, nest values are null

```
libelle=Article AB,
description=null,
dimension=null,
enabled=true,
categorie=null,
famille=null,
type=null,
picture=null,
prixVente=0.0,
poids=0.0,
status=null,
barcode=null,
annee=0,
boitier=null,
mouvement=null,
taille=0,
diametre=0.0
```

this is my post function in front

```
 post(url: string, body: any, options?: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<any>(url, JSON.stringify(body), newHeaders(options));
    }
```

this is my Rest controller

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/article", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_CREATE_ARTICLE')")
    public ResponseEntity<Long> addArticle(@RequestBody ArticleDto article) throws Exception {
        
        article = articleService.createArticle(article);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<Long>(article.getId(), HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
```

ArticleDto

```
package com.sighimo.dto;



import com.sighimo.common.AuditBaseDto;
import com.sighimo.common.Utils;
import com.sighimo.common.enumeration.Categorie;
import com.sighimo.common.enumeration.Dimension;
import com.sighimo.common.enumeration.Famille;
import com.sighimo.common.enumeration.Mouvement;
import com.sighimo.common.enumeration.Type;
import com.sighimo.models.Article;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Data
@Getter
@Setter
public class ArticleDto extends AuditBaseDto {

    /** Libelle */
    private String libelle;

    /** Description */
    private String description;

    /** Adresse */
    private Dimension dimension;
    
    private boolean enabled = true;
    //Enum
    private Categorie categorie;
    //Enum
    private Famille famille;
    //Enum
    private Type type;
    private String picture;
    private double prixVente;
    private double poids;
    private String status;
    private String barcode;
    private int annee;
    private String boitier;
    //Enum
    private Mouvement mouvement;
    // pierre;
    private int taille;
    private double diametre;

                        
    /**
     * Constructeur par défaut.
     */
    public ArticleDto() {
        super();
    }
    
    /**
     * Constructeur.
     * @param id clé primaire
     */
    public ArticleDto(Long id) {
        super(id);
    }
    
    public ArticleDto(Article article, boolean collections, int level) {
        super();
        convertToDto(this, article, collections, level);
    }

    public ArticleDto(Article article, boolean collections) {
        super();
        convertToDto(this, article, collections, 0);
    }
    
    public ArticleDto(Article article) {
        super();
        convertToDto(this, article, false, 0);
    }
    
    public Article convertIdToEntity(Article article, ArticleDto articleDto) {

        article.setId(articleDto.getId());

        return article;
    }
    
    public ArticleDto convertIdToDto(ArticleDto articleDto, Article article) {

        articleDto.setId(article.getId());

        return articleDto;
    }   
    
    public Article convertToEntity(Article article, ArticleDto articleDto) {

        if (article != null) {
            article = convertIdToEntity(article,articleDto);
            article.setLibelle(articleDto.getLibelle());
            article.setDescription(articleDto.getDescription());
            article.setPicture(articleDto.getPicture());
            article.setStatus(articleDto.getStatus());
            article.setPrixVente(articleDto.getPrixVente());
            article.setBarcode(articleDto.getBarcode());
            //Bijouterie
            if(articleDto.getCategorie() != null) {
                article.setCategorie(articleDto.getCategorie().name());
            }
            if(articleDto.getType() != null) {
                article.setType(articleDto.getType().name());
            }
            if(articleDto.getMouvement() != null) {
                article.setMouvement(articleDto.getMouvement().name());
            }
            if(articleDto.getDimension() != null) {
                article.setDimension(articleDto.getDimension().name());
            }
            if(articleDto.getFamille() != null) {
                article.setFamille(articleDto.getFamille().name());
            }
            article.setPoids(articleDto.getPoids());
            article.setTaille(articleDto.getTaille());
            //Horlogerie
            article.setAnnee(articleDto.getAnnee());
            article.setBoitier(articleDto.getBoitier());
            article.setDiametre(articleDto.getDiametre());
            article.setEnabled(articleDto.isEnabled());
            
            
        }
        
        return article;
    }   

    public ArticleDto mappedCustomDto( ArticleDto articleDto, String[] includes, String[] excludes) {

        if (Utils.isNoEmpty(includes) || Utils.isNoEmpty(excludes)) {
            if (Utils.isNoEmpty(includes)) {
                Utils.copyIncludesProperties(articleDto, this, includes);
            }
            if (Utils.isNoEmpty(excludes)) {
                Utils.copyExcludesProperties(articleDto, this, excludes);
            }

            this.id = articleDto.getId();
            
            return this;
        }

        return articleDto;
    }
    
    public ArticleDto convertToDto(ArticleDto articleDto, Article article, boolean collections, int level) {
        
        level++;
        if (articleDto != null && level <= maxLevel) {

                articleDto = convertIdToDto(articleDto, article);
                articleDto.setLibelle(article.getLibelle());
                articleDto.setDescription(article.getDescription());
                articleDto.setPicture(article.getPicture());
                articleDto.setStatus(article.getStatus());
                articleDto.setPrixVente(article.getPrixVente());
                articleDto.setBarcode(article.getBarcode());
                articleDto.setEnabled(article.isEnabled());
                articleDto.setPoids(article.getPoids());
                //Bijouterie
                articleDto.setDimension(Dimension.forValue(article.getDimension()));
                articleDto.setCategorie(Categorie.forValue(article.getCategorie()));
                articleDto.setFamille(Famille.forValue(article.getFamille()));
                articleDto.setType(Type.forValue(article.getType()));
                articleDto.setTaille(article.getTaille());
                //Horlogerie
                articleDto.setMouvement(Mouvement.forValue(article.getMouvement()));
                articleDto.setAnnee(article.getAnnee());
                articleDto.setBoitier(article.getBoitier());
                articleDto.setDiametre(article.getDiametre());
                
                articleDto.setCreatedBy(article.getCreatedBy());
                articleDto.setCreatedOn(Utils.dateTimeToString(article.getCreatedOn()));
                articleDto.setUpdatedBy(article.getUpdatedBy());
                articleDto.setUpdatedOn(Utils.dateTimeToString(article.getUpdatedOn()));
                
            
                if (collections) {
                }               
            
        }
        
        return articleDto;
    }   
    
}
```

I tried to add @JsonProperty, @Builder but same problem

**EDIT :**
using Objectmapper I'm getting this error:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "label" (class com.sighimo.dto.ArticleDto), not marked as ignorable (18 known properties: "barcode", "enabled", "libelle", "dimension", "taille", "famille", "status", "diametre", "categorie", "poids", "type", "id", "description", "picture", "prixVente", "annee", "boitier", "mouvement"])

Comment: can you add the article DTO?

Comment: Can you try the below answer

Comment: @YJR, I tried it but no luck, I tried to deserialize it manually it looks like it does not recognize nested objects of type Enum fields, so it skips all the following fields I added the error to question.

Comment: You are right it can be the issue

Comment: You,’re sending categorie as an object but on the server-side you’re declaring it as an Enum. You may just pass the enum name like `categorie: BELDI`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `@AllArgConstructor` ,`@NoArgsConstructor` and `@RequiredArgConstructor` to the `ArticleDTO` class and remove the manually added constructors. That annotations automatically create constructors for you. Then add above annotations to all other classses such as `Dimension` which have refetences inside `articleDTO`. This should work.